# an error "(error) ERR illegal address " happen in redis command

Tags: redis

```
r-vy1ba7c1e3d09574.redis.rds.aliyuncs.com:6379>
r-vy1ba7c1e3d09574.redis.rds.aliyuncs.com:6379>
r-vy1ba7c1e3d09574.redis.rds.aliyuncs.com:6379> auth asdkfjlasjdf
(error) ERR illegal address
r-vy1ba7c1e3d09574.redis.rds.aliyuncs.com:6379>
r-vy1ba7c1e3d09574.redis.rds.aliyuncs.com:6379>
```

When I execute that command to verify, an error is caused.
The password of auth is correct!
I don't understand the meaning of the error.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It seems you are in aliyun, I face the same problem, so I ask it in the aliyun forum, https://bbs.aliyun.com/read/540217.html?displayMode=1

I solve this problem finally, you should set the redis's white list correctly in Redis-> Security Setting.
You should add your ECS's private ip in the white list, not public ip.

Comment: redis for aliyun has 2 connect address , public network adderss vs private netword addres, this problem is because you used public address, change to private address should be resolve you probelm